# Which symbolic programming language for manipulation of nonlinear equations?

Tags: matlab, mathematica, symbolic-computation

I have a set of (multivariate, nonlinear) equations which I want wo modify according to my own rules, i.e. not in a standard ways such as matlab's simplify function. I am looking for a mathematical symbolic programming language, which is able to do these things.

Most importantly, I want to do multivariate calculus and extract and change subexpressions of formulas in a user-defined way.
I tried matlab symbolic toolbox, it is very intuitive but does not offer much functionality if one wants to do non-standard stuff.
I also tried sympy but for a mathematician it seems complicated and not well developed. E.g. I did not even find a usable dot product function for vector-valued symbolic variables.

Does anyone have any advices about good symbolic programming language?

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: It sounds a bit ambitious, but there is considerable experience of symbolic manipulation in Macsyma (see also [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)) which uses Lisp as the underlying programming language.  If Python is more your forte, then I'd look at the symbolic computation aspects of [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), which incorporates Maxima but has its own growing functionality of that kind.